# rename files in a selected directory using if else c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am very new to C# and having trouble adapting/writing code for me needs, apologies if I use the wrong terms. I am developing a Windows Form App to rename only word documents within a given directory. I wish to utilize an "if else" approach to rename files dependent on what combobox item is selected.

Example:

- Users are given a drop down menu to select a rename value depending on what item is selected (if the user selects "`<StudentCode>_Draft`" or "`<StudentCode>_Final`", the word file will be renamed to `<StudentCode>_Draft.docx` or `<StudentCode>_Final.docx` respectively).
- The rename function would have to be split into a sting using '_' to delim as the file name is always be:
  `<Assignment name> allocated on <website>_<StudentCode>_<attempt>_<Year>-<Month>-<Date>-<Hour>-<Minute>-<Second>.docx`
  ... as that is the output value from the website.

Would I need to specify the If Else function in `private void RenameFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`?

If so, here is the code I currently have (found from another project);

```
private void RenameFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo($"{PathStamp.Text}");
    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles($"{ExtensionCombo.Text}");
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        File.Copy(
            sourceFileName: $"{file.FullName}",
            destFileName:
                $"{PathStamp.Text}{file.LastWriteTime.Date.Year}-{file.LastWriteTime.Date.Month}-" +
                $"{file.LastWriteTime.Date.Day}-{file.LastWriteTime.Hour}{file.LastWriteTime.Minute}{file.LastWriteTime.Second}{file.Extension}"
        );
    }
    
    Refresh();
}
```

---

- `DirectoryInfo($"{PathStamp.Text}")` refers to grabbing the selected folder from a text box that displays the file path
- `d.GetFiles($"{ExtensionCombo.Text}");` refers to the current combo box where the items are located for the user to select an option. Currently, the options are 'StudentCode_Draft' and 'StudentCode_Final'

Comment: You shouldn’t be using interpolated strings like that, they’re also implicitly culture-sensitive which is why I recommend avoiding them.

Comment: @Dai, with the interpolated strings - are you referring to File.Copy? If so - I have two list boxes in my program (one to show folder directory with the current files and another to give users a preview of what the new names would look like without committing to rename the files). I hope that is more clear

Comment: Yes, I am referring to your `File.Copy` arguments. You can greatly simplify it to make it more readable *and* make it work consistently regardless of the user’s culture settings.

Comment: That is the argument I would like to turn into If Else depending on what combobox item is selected. Example;

```if (StudentCode_Draft is selected)
{
                 File.Move({StudentCode_Draft}{file.Extension}");
 
} 
else if (StudentCode_Final is selected) 
{
  File.Move({StudentCode_Final}{file.Extension}");
} 
else
```

Comment: You’re still misusing interpolated strings, though.

Comment: Apologies, I'm a teacher attempting to create a renaming tool for other teachers I work with. I have very little exposure to C#. With the current government and education reporting standards, we have to have out file names is a very specific order. With 100+ students per teacher, the task currently takes hours to rename files.

Comment: This could be easily answered, however I am struggling to understand what the file names look like, and how you want them to be renamed Can you put a couple of actual file name examples i.e inputs and outputs?

Comment: Certainly. Currently, all the assessment files that we download from the submission portal follow the same format; _“Assignment name allocated on website_StudentCode(e.g. jsmit1)_attempt_Year-Month-Date-Hour-Minute-Second”_.

I would like the output to be _"StudentCode_Draft"_ if the user has selected the combobox item with text containing *'StudentCode_Draft'*.

Comment: so you want to rename all files in a directory from something like `Assignment name allocated on website_jsmit1_attempt_Year-Month-Date-Hour-Minute-Second.docx` to `{StudentCode}_Draft.docx` ? where student code is something like `jsmit1`

Comment: Correct - sorry if my explanation was convoluted

Comment: What if there are more than one file with a particular student code? obviously that is not allowed by the operating system (i.e to have more than one file with the exact same name)... or should that never happen?

Comment: Each student code is unique. If a class and 3 John Smiths for example, they could have the codes `jsmit18`, `jsmit172` and `jsmit581`. Thus,  that can never happen

Answer (score 0):

So basically you could use regex to pick out the Student code:

```
\S*_(\S*)_\S*_\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+
```

The above just validates the dashes and underscores to find the student code. Also I have used a switch with an index to work out what was chosen, you could use an `if` statement if you choose and a string comparison.

**Given**

```
private static readonly Regex _regex = new (@"\S*_(\S*)_\S*_\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

**Example**

```
private static bool TryGetFileName(int selectedIndex, string fileName, out string outputName)
{
   outputName = null;
   var match = _regex.Match(fileName);

   // If the file name doesn't look right, return false
   if (!match.Success)
      return false;

   var suffix = selectedIndex switch
   {
      0 => "Draft",
      1 => "Final",
      _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(selectedIndex))
   };

   var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
   var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

   outputName = Path.Combine(path, $"{match.Groups[1].Value}_{suffix}{extension}");
   return true;
}

public static void Rename(int selectedIndex, string path, string searchPattern)
{
   foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern))
      if(TryGetFileName(selectedIndex, file,out var outputName))
         File.Move(file, outputName);
}
```

**Usage**

```
Rename(SelectedIndex,@"D:\SomeExamplePath","*.docx");
```

**Simple Tests**

Some examples of what will work and what won't:

```
var listOfPaths = new string[]
{
   @"D:\Test\AssignmentName allocated on SomeWebSite_Bob1_2342343_2021-1-2-23-45-23.docx",
   @"D:\Test\test\test\fhjfghjgj SomeWebSite_Bob2_2342343_2021-1-2-23-45-23.docx",
   @"D:\Test\test\test\fhjfghjgj SomeWebSite_Bob2_2021-1-2-23-45-23.docx"
};

foreach (var item in listOfPaths)
{
   if(TryGetFileName(1, item,out var name))
      Console.WriteLine("Success : "+ name);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("Failed : " + item);
}
```

**Output**

```
Success : D:\Test\Bob1_Final.docx
Success : D:\Test\test\test\Bob2_Final.docx
Failed : D:\Test\test\test\fhjfghjgj SomeWebSite_Bob2_2021-1-2-23-45-23.docx
```

Comment: No dice unfortunately, I'm going to scrap my existing code base (taken from another file renaming project) and try start from the ground up. Thank you very much for your help. I'll attempt to incorporate what I have learnt here into the new project.